# How can I rectify the error Build failed when naming c files with '&'?

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm getting errors when I try to name an C file with '&' (like 'Sum of Int&float'). But the error is cleared when I remove the '&'. Why does naming with '&' produce errors.I am using Eclipse IDE for c/c++ 2021-03.

````
make all
Building file: ../src/int&float.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/int&float.d" -MT"src/int&float.o" -o "src/int&float.o" "../src/int&float.c"
Finished building: ../src/int&float.c
Building target: Sum of int&float
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc  -o "Sum of int&float" ./src/int&float.o   
/bin/sh: 1: float.o: not found
make: *** [makefile:32: Sum of int&float] Error 127
gcc: error: ./src/int: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
18:02:24 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 685ms)```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` character is a special character to the shell, used to put a process in the background.

You could put the filename in quotes, but it's best to avoid using that character in filenames for reasons like this.

Comment: I tried with some special characters like '%' but it doesn't seem to produce such an error

Comment: @Nidheesh That's because `%` is not considered a special character by the shell.  Take a look at the man page for "sh" for more details.

Comment: @Nidheesh I'd spare that time. Do what everybody else does: don't use fancy characters in file names.

Comment: In filenames, you'd better avoid non-ASCII characters and spaces. Operating systems  manage them well, but many applications are "surprised" by spaces or UTF8 non-ASCII characters in the path or filename. The two characters that are perfectly safe in filenames are underscore (_) and minus (-).

Comment: @Nidheesh Also, consider that one day you may want to compile your files using some build systems other than makefile and them some "odd" characters in filenames may have unexpected meaning there, e.g. a begginning of a comment or just filename separator. Spaces in filenames may also lead to very strange results in bash scripts etc.

Comment: @zkoza Does it include system terminal too?

Comment: @Nidheesh Yes. The special characters include at least* &, <, >, ;, |.But as I said, for me the safe character set of filenames is Latin alphabet (a-z, A-Z), digits, minus and underscore. You can use other character, including UTF-8, like żółćść, but sometimes they are incorrectly processed by IDEs etc.

Comment: @zkoza An doubt off topic; how can I round off a float output, like 80.199997 to 80.2000(at least four places)

Comment: @Nidheesh That's a separate question, but first search the site as it's probably a duplicate.

Comment: @Nidheesh See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed or wait for C++20's `format` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format, or get well-acquainted with old good `printf`. Or search stackoverflow.